# Calculate curvature from smooth.spline in R

Tags: r, spline

is there a way to calculate the curvature in a specific point having a smooth.spline curve (or similar)in R?
The curve is calculate from a set of x,y points.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: perhaps `?splinefun` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one is actually very easy *if* you know that there is a `predict()` method for objects created by `smooth.spline()` and that this method has an argument `deriv` which allows you to predict a given derivative (in your case the second derivative is required) instead of points on the spline.

```
 cars.spl <- with(cars, smooth.spline(speed, dist, df = 3))
 with(cars, predict(cars.spl, x = speed, deriv = 2))
```

Which gives:

```
$x
 [1]  4  4  7  7  8  9 10 10 10 11 11 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15
[26] 15 16 16 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 22 23 24 24 24 24 25

$y
 [1] -6.492030e-05 -6.492030e-05  3.889944e-02  3.889944e-02  5.460044e-02
 [6]  7.142609e-02  6.944645e-02  6.944645e-02  6.944645e-02  9.273343e-02
[11]  9.273343e-02  1.034153e-01  1.034153e-01  1.034153e-01  1.034153e-01
[16]  5.057841e-02  5.057841e-02  5.057841e-02  5.057841e-02  1.920888e-02
[21]  1.920888e-02  1.920888e-02  1.920888e-02  1.111307e-01  1.111307e-01
[26]  1.111307e-01  1.616749e-01  1.616749e-01  1.801385e-01  1.801385e-01
[31]  1.801385e-01  1.550027e-01  1.550027e-01  1.550027e-01  1.550027e-01
[36]  2.409237e-01  2.409237e-01  2.409237e-01  2.897166e-01  2.897166e-01
[41]  2.897166e-01  2.897166e-01  2.897166e-01  1.752232e-01  1.095682e-01
[46] -1.855994e-03 -1.855994e-03 -1.855994e-03 -1.855994e-03  4.478382e-05
```

where `$y` is the second derivative of the fitted spline, evaluated at the observed `speed` values in the data used to fit the spline. Of course you can plug in any values you want here, such as 100 values equally spaced over the range of `speed`. For example:

```
newspeed <- with(cars, seq(min(speed), max(speed), length = 100))
curvature <- predict(cars.spl, x = newspeed, deriv = 2)

plot(curvature, type = "l")
```